Should mods be able to accept an answer?
I often see that the asker of a question forgets to accept an answer that is really good and has been upvoted several times. I think it would be valuable to have the questions marked as accepted so people instantly see that there is a good answer. 
Wouldn't it be an idea to have answers be accepted after some period of time  iff (if and only if) there is no other accepted answer for that question?
As a suggestion, we could say after 2 weeks when a question has reached a critical value of 5 upvotes (which is already quite high in many cased) that a moderator may accept the answer (or a review period starts similar to close votes). 

Such changes are beyond what we can do given that this site is only part of the bigger Stack Exchange network.
On the meta site of Stack Exchange however, this topic has been raised before. In case you are interested you can fight for the proposal there, but on this site, this is beyond our reach.

Let me immediately accept and upvote your answer. Reading through the SE questions, I came to the conclusion that it may not be the best decision (interestingly an answer that was only accepted once worked the best for me). Though they only discuss potential moderator acceptance I think the point is made. Let the upvotes count then :)
